# Move to Next Window after Quitting Another

Tags: mac, keyboard, window-manager

On my MacBook Pro, after quitting an app with ⌘-Q, I have to manually set the focus on the next window.  Is there a way to configure it so the focus switches to the next window?

Comment: Focus goes to the next app in line [ie, the one that was last in front before the one you Quit], depending on usage. The OS can't know which you think should be next.

Comment: Sure, I understand that, but sometimes the focus is not on a window.  I have to click on the next window.

Comment: Focus has to be on *something*. If it's not on a Window, then check what app shows as front-most in the menu bar. If it's Finder, then focus could be the desktop [which *is* technically a window]